# JavaScript link underline styling

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm using an onmouseover/onmouseout over a table cell to change the styling for an image and a link in the cell. It works but is overriding the CSS link styling, namely the `text-decoration: none` and font color. I've tried correcting with inline CSS, but no dice. Any ideas? Also, I know the code is hideous. I just want to get it working before I put it into an external js file.

```
<td 
  onmouseover="
    document.getElementById('myImage').style.border='3px solid #334f92'; 
    document.getElementbyId('myLink').style.fontWeight='bold';
    document.getElementbyId('myLink').style.textDecorationLine='none';"" 
  onmouseout="
    document.getElementById('myImage').style.border='1px solid #000000';
    document.getElementbyId('myLink').style.fontWeight='normal';
">
```

Comment: What do you mean by overriding ? Is the style not getting applied for elements having Id "link" ?

Comment: this is a CSS question/problem tag it appropriately to get real help.

Answer (score 2):

First off, good thing you recognize that writing inline event listeners are not very conventional (and also hideous).

Have you considered achieving this through CSS? It may be a lot simpler and would eliminate the need for two separate event listeners for mouseover and mouseout. You would simply use the :hover css selector like so:

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  /* Added padding for demonstration purposes */
  padding: 20px;
}
td:hover {
  border: 3px solid #334f92;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}

td:hover a {
color: orange;
}

td:hover img {
border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
  </td>
  <td>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

In addition, if you wanted to style an image within the `<td>` tag, you can do this:

```
td:hover img {
  /*Apply CSS to image here*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! I tried CSS, but couldn't find a way to get :hover from one element to trigger formatting for the other (I.E. if the mouse was over the text, the image lost its hover border and vice-versa)

Comment: @WillHiebs Take a look at my updated code above. As long as the a tag and the img tag are child elements within the td tag it will continue to apply the css properties.

Comment: Thanks! I'm putting it in now, but it looks like it'll be workable! Much appreciated!